# Wordpress new theme developement / testing, whilst old theme continues to run live

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for some wordpress advice with regards to new theme development.

I have a wordpress theme which is running live at the mo, my old 2011 website.

I would like to develop my new 2012 theme on the same wordpress install, but for my eyes only. And for the old 2011 theme to continue to run live.

Is there some simple function that can redirect me to a new theme, using my IP or something?

Or is there a better way to develop new themes, on existing installions?

Any advice or links would be awesome thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution to this is to have a separate development environment either in a sub-directory of your live site or via a local server.  I would recommend this as it helps with versioning and not having to worry about breaking your live site.

If there is some reason why you cannot do this then good luck finding a more amiable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to build it on localhost but if you don't want to build it in your localhost then you can use the WordPress [**theme switcher plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/parallels-themes-switcher/faq/) that is perfect for your need. This is [**another theme switcher**](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/wiki/ThemeSwitcher), if you like it.

Comment: Thanks Sheikh, the Parallels Themes Switcher maybe the ideal solution, just checking it out now

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to just make a DEV instance - backup and copy over the db and link it to a copied instance of wordpress and play around until you get the theme right - then just copy the theme folder back to the PROD instance

Comment: Thank you also for the tip :-)